# Magento 2 Shopping Cart add Images and Text below Proceed to checkout button

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart

I want to add some text and images below proceed to checkout button on cart page but I am not able to find the file so that I can add my classes and images as well as text.

Please suggest me in which file I will need to update.

Below is attached screenshot please check it:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

enable frontend template hint from admin and you will find the file of your theme for checkout page.

```
/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart.phtml
```

Comment: Already enabled but not getting exactly.

Comment: please choose store scope first then ENABLE template path hint for frontend

Comment: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/onepage/link.phtml
proceed to checkout button is coming from this template

Comment: vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart.phtml
check if you have same file in your theme folder and edit it. Make sure you take backup before making any changes.

Comment: @John vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/templates/cart.phtml  //this will work for me.thanks

Comment: Accept this as answer, so it will help other developers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewModel to add custom content. You can create custom module for this.

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block name="customcartblock" template="Anshu_Custom::customcartblock.phtml" after="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="viewModel" xsi:type="object">Anshu\Custom\ViewModel\Customcartblock</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/ViewModel/Customcartblock.php**

```
<?php

namespace Anshu\Custom\ViewModel;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Block\ArgumentInterface;
use Magento\Framework\DataObject;

class Customcartblock extends DataObject implements ArgumentInterface
{
    public function getSomeThing()
    {
        return 'This is the custom text.';
    }
}
```

**app/code/Anshu/Custom/view/frontend/templates/customcartblock.phtml**

```
<?php
$viewModel = $block->getData('viewModel');
var_dump($viewModel->getSomeThing());
```

This is the sample code. You can modify it according to your requirement.